# Search algorithm (graph) in a single java file

Tags: java, algorithm

I have to implement a search algorithm for a school assignment. Right now, i'm having problems with sole java implementation. Here's the code i have at the moment (i have been basing myself in some code i found here in stackoverflow for the dfs search, then i have to add verifications to meet the project criteria):

```
import java.util.*;

public class dfs<Grafo> {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    class Grafo{
         private Map<Integer, LinkedHashSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap();

         public void addEdge(int source, int destiny) {
                LinkedHashSet<Integer> adjacente = map.get(source);
                if(adjacente==null) {
                    adjacente = new LinkedHashSet();
                    map.put(source, adjacente);
                }
                adjacente.add(destiny);
            }

            public void addLink(int source, int destiny) {
                addEdge(source, destiny);
                addEdge(destiny, source);
            }

            public LinkedList<Integer> adjacentNodes(int last) {
                LinkedHashSet<Integer> adjacente = map.get(last);
                if(adjacente==null) {
                    return new LinkedList();
                }
                return new LinkedList<Integer>(adjacente);
            }
    }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numVertices = input.nextInt();
    int numLinks = input.nextInt();
    int startNode = input.nextInt();
    int endNode = startNode;

    Grafo mapa = new Grafo();

    for(int i = 0; i<numLinks; i++){
        mapa.addLink(input.nextInt(), input.nextInt());
    }

    List<ArrayList<Integer>> paths = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    Integer currentNode = startNode;
    List<Integer> visited = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    visited.add(startNode);
    new dfs().findAllPaths(mapa, visited, paths, currentNode);

    for(ArrayList<Integer> path : paths){
        for (Integer node : path) {
            System.out.print(node);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
}

}

private void findAllPaths(Grafo mapa, List<Integer> visited,
        List<ArrayList<Integer>> paths, Integer currentNode) {

    if (currentNode.equals(startNode)) { 
        paths.add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(visited.toArray())));
        return;
    }

    else {
        LinkedList<Integer> nodes = mapa.adjacentNodes(currentNode);    
        for (Integer node : nodes) {
            if (visited.contains(node)) {
                continue;
            } 
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            temp.addAll(visited);
            temp.add(node);          
            findAllPaths(mapa, temp, paths, node);
        }
    }

} 

}
```

The problem i have with this, is that i can only turn in a single java file, so i'm putting everything in this single file.
When i get to the findAllPaths function he does not recognise the "startNode" constant (eclipse says that it cannot be be resolved to a variable) and he says "adjacentNodes" function is not defined for the type Grafo.

Is there anyway i can solve this problem or do i have to rethink the way i'm doing this, if so, what's a good way to implement this?

Comment: Why can you only deliver a single java file? That's completely against OO in so many levels. Can't you deliver a runnable .jar with your multiple classes and their source code?

Comment: I know... that's the rules... I can only turn in a single java or c++ file.

Comment: First, I think your Grafo class should be outside of main() function. Second, I am not sure if another class inside can be used as generic type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others seem to have addressed some of your coding issues, so I just wanted to illustrate how to work with the single file constraint.

Suppose you had 3 classes, Edge, Node, and Graph that you developed in three separate files. Here's how you could combine them:

```
// in file GraphSearchHomework.java
public class GraphSearchHomework {
  public static class Edge {
    // ... Edge code here ...
    // You can reference Nodes and Graphs
    // just as if this was in a separate file
  }

  public static class Node {
    // ... Node code here ...
    // You can reference Edges and Graphs
    // just as if this was in a separate file
  }

  public static class Graph {
    // ... Graph code here ...
    // You can reference Edges and Nodes
    // just as if this was in a separate file
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    // This main can instantiate Graphs, Nodes, Edges
    // Keep this simple, though. Most code belongs outside of main.
  }
}
```

You seem to have made some mistakes trying to force this into one file. If it helps you, go ahead and develop each class separately and then combine them.

Answer (score 1):

`startNode` is a local variable in `main()`, and thus is not recognized by `findAllPaths()` [remember, one might invoke this from a method which is not main...] java has static [binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding) so it forbids this.

You can add it as a parameter to `findAllPaths()`, or you can make `startNode` a field in your class `dfs`, and then `findAllPaths()` will be able to access it.

Same idea for `Grafo` - you declared it as a method inner class, you should declare it as an inner class for the class - otherwise only `main()` will "know" how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned out your errors and warnings for you.

Still doesn't run well, but you can sort that out on your own..

Looks like you don't need the outer class dts. If you make the Grafo your top level class it becomes much cleaner.

If you make the startNode a class variable you can instantiate it in your main method and you can access it in your other methods.

Also when you instantiate generic classes you should specify the generic type like this:

```
new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

I wouldn't hand it in just yet, but at least the structure is a bit cleaner..

```
import java.util.*;

public class Grafo {

        private Map<Integer, LinkedHashSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, LinkedHashSet<Integer>>();
        private int startNode;



        public Grafo(int startNode) {
            super();
            this.startNode = startNode;
        }

        public void addEdge(int source, int destiny) {
            LinkedHashSet<Integer> adjacente = map.get(source);
            if(adjacente==null) {
                adjacente = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
                map.put(source, adjacente);
            }
            adjacente.add(destiny);
        }

        public void addLink(int source, int destiny) {
            addEdge(source, destiny);
            addEdge(destiny, source);
        }

        public LinkedList<Integer> adjacentNodes(int last) {
            LinkedHashSet<Integer> adjacente = map.get(last);
            if(adjacente==null) {
                return new LinkedList<Integer>();
            }
            return new LinkedList<Integer>(adjacente);
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numVertices = input.nextInt();
        int numLinks = input.nextInt();
        int startNode = input.nextInt();
        int endNode = startNode;

        Grafo mapa = new Grafo(startNode);

        for(int i = 0; i<numLinks; i++){
            mapa.addLink(input.nextInt(), input.nextInt());
        }

        List<ArrayList<Integer>> paths = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        Integer currentNode = startNode;
        List<Integer> visited = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        visited.add(startNode);
        mapa.findAllPaths(mapa, visited, paths, currentNode);

        for(ArrayList<Integer> path : paths){
            for (Integer node : path) {
                System.out.print(node);
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    private void findAllPaths(Grafo mapa, List<Integer> visited,
            List<ArrayList<Integer>> paths, Integer currentNode) {

        if (currentNode.equals(startNode)) { 
            paths.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(visited));
            return;
        }

        else {
            LinkedList<Integer> nodes = mapa.adjacentNodes(currentNode);    
            for (Integer node : nodes) {
                if (visited.contains(node)) {
                    continue;
                } 
                List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                temp.addAll(visited);
                temp.add(node);          
                findAllPaths(mapa, temp, paths, node);
            }
        }

    } 

}
```

Comment: answers for questions tagged with "homework" should not give answers - but guidelines how to solve the problem and learn on the process. Your answer does not even explain what was wrong with the original code, please fix it.

Comment: My bad. I see the other answers are a lot better.. I added some explanations though..

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm now having problems because the output is not what i wished it was, but i will try to figure out what is happening. At least i'm able to run my program!